# The way to speak and write if someone sits on someone's thigh/ pelvis or leg

Tags: sentence-construction

[image]

I just want to know that the way we can express when someone sits on the top of someones thigh or pelvis like I attached the picture.

> She have sat on my thigh.

Will the above sentence seem natural way to speak and write?

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you're asking here. You could say, "She sat on my thigh," or "she had been sitting on my thigh," or a whole bunch of different tenses...what is the question here?

Comment: The usual term would be "on your lap".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The common term is:

- She sat "on my lap".
- She sat "in my lap".

We aren't generally specific about where unless it's specifically important to the description.

Comment: is there any difference between the two sentence you mentioned?

Comment: Not that I can tell... I think there may be a slight regional difference... I tend to prefer "on my lap" and I'm American.

Comment: Yes, "on my lap". "She sat on my thigh" would be a very unlikely thing for a fluent English-speaker to say. You might say "she sat on my leg" if she was sitting on just one leg, like straddling your leg.

Comment: If someone sat on your abdomen you'd probably say "she sat on my stomach". You'd have to be lying down, face up. If you were face down, you'd say "she sat on my back".

Comment: @Jay or even knee... with children, they're often "perched on a knee"

Comment: I have created a new question as suggested by Catija: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75298/the-way-to-call-the-position-of-babies

Comment: I think the on/in distinction would probably depend on the relative sizes of the people. A baby or small dog might sit "in" my lap, but anybody else is going to be "on".

Comment: Usually if something is in my lap, it's like a plate of food I spilled. Girls sit on my lap. Well, I'm married now, so... it's not plural anymore ;-)