# The way to call the position of babies

Tags: sentence-construction

Usually mother takes her baby  in different way on different position on her body, and she holds her baby very tightly or loosely depends on the position of a baby. It could be on her lap when she  takes on thigh.  But when they take their baby on abdomen or top of the abdomen or other different position, we can we call in natural way?

I have added some positions so you can have  idea  that what I am looking for. :)

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]

Comment: okay i am trying to  get similar image.\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number 3 is definitely described as "on her stomach". I'd be surprised if anyone has another phrase for this, at least one that they claim is commonly used.

Number 4 we'd say "on her lap". It's a little ambiguous as by "on her lap" we usually mean sitting sideways relative to the person "underneath". But the baby is clearly on her lap.

Number 2 we would say she is "holding the baby" or "the baby is in her arms". I don't think we'd normally say the baby is "on ..." anything here.

Number 1 is probably the trickiest. I think most fluent English speakers would say the baby is "on her shoulder". Yes, that's ambiguous, potentially misleading if taken literally. If the baby was sitting on her shoulder, like with his arms above the top of her head, we'd also say he was "on her shoulder". Though I suppose in the case of your picture we say the baby is "lying on her shoulder" while in the other case I just described we would say he is "sitting on her shoulder". Alternatively, it wouldn't be terribly odd for someone to describe number 1 as "on her stomach".

Comment: +1. but I think #2 is trickiest, not #1.  The plural **shoulders** would be used to mean literally sitting on her shoulders; singular **on her shoulder** would be understood to mean its head resting on her shoulder. With  #2, on the other hand, a person might think she were cradling the baby in her arms when hearing "in her arms". I'd say she was "standing with the baby".

Comment: #3 could also be "on her belly".

Comment: I would describe #1 as "in her arms", or more likely, I would say she is "holding the baby", same as #2. #4 could easily be "in" her lap, as the baby is pretty small and surrounded. "on her belly" sounds pretty good for #2, as well as "stomach". Pretty much the same thing.